# How to make children overlap its parent using z-index

Tags: html, css

So, I have a parent element with id #bronze and a children element of class .price-container. What I want to do is to have the children element overlaping the parent element, meaning that its z coordinate should be higher. However it seems like z-index is being completely ignored even though, the element is relatively positioned.

**Why is the z-index not working in this case?**

Thanks

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: inherit;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-container * {
  align-self: center;
}

.flex-container .second-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.second-container>div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 3rem;
  background-size: 150px, 150px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  z-index: 3;
}

.second-container>div .price-container {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  top: 12rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: 0;
}

#bronze-price {
  border: 2px solid #BE5A06;
}

#bronze {
  background: orange
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="second-container">
    <div id="bronze">
      <div class="price-container" id="bronze-price"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

You should use `top: 6rem;` I see you have more than what you expect. also I used `#bronze-price` selector to define the code.

```css
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: inherit;
  justify-content: center;
}

.flex-container * {
  align-self: center;
}

.flex-container .second-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  max-width: 100%;
  height: 20vh;
  margin-bottom: 5rem;
}

.second-container>div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 3rem;
  background-size: 150px, 150px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  z-index: 3;
   border:2px solid black;
}

.second-container>div .price-container {
  height: 40px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  position: relative;
  top: 6rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
  z-index: -1; 
}

#bronze-price {
  border: 5px solid #BE5A06;
  display:inline-block;
  z-index:0;
}

#bronze {
  background: orange
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="second-container">
    <div id="bronze">
      <div class="price-container" id="bronze-price"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it would be good to at least hightlight what did you do. Actually it's hard (even impossible) to find what you did